# How does TestNG look for Test Classes?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, testng

How does TestNG work when it is looking for its test classes?

I created a separate project from my TestNG project using JavaFX to create a GUI, when the GUI is run it enables you to select an XML file and then the path to the testNG XML is saved in a variable.

When I run the following code:

```
String xmlFileName = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
List<String> testFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                            
testFilesList.add(xmlFileName); //test suite resides in the working directory's root folder
testng.setTestSuites(testFilesList); //you can addd multiple suites either here by adding multiple files or include all suites needed in the testng.xml file 
testng.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
testng.addListener(htmlRep); 
testng.run();
```

I get an error saying that it cannot find my test classes inside the XML.

> [TestNG] [ERROR]
>
> Cannot find class in classpath: com.emc.qe.u360.tests.LogoutTests

I then decided to make a java class within my TestNG project, and copy the code over and it still gives the same error message.

Where is TestNG looking for the test classes when the above code is run?

What difference is the code above from manually running the XML from eclipse itself? The code seems to be working, as from what I can see if the code for running the XML was broken or not working, it wouldn't be able to give me that error as it wouldn't be able to determine what is specified in the XML.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Just for background information, currently I am using Jenkins to run the tests, what I'm trying to do with the GUI is to create an alternative solution to running the tests outside of the Project/Framework, that can be used universally, a user can just select their XML and then the tests will be executed.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar.  When I pass multiple TestNG test classes to my Spring-Web-App test runner, if even one of them has a bad canonical class name, then the whole suite crashes with TestNGException where I would rather catch the problem on a per-class basis and then continue.  I think I am probably going to have to check the class names before I assemble the suite, and catch the exception earlier.

Comment: Hey @djangofan. I don't think I would have to solution to your question as I am in the very early stages of my development. If you want to start a private chat and discuss or projects, maybe something I have done may help or benefit you?

Comment: its ok.  i dont need help.  i mentioned it because it sounds like you might run into a similar problem with your FX test runner.

Answer (score 1):

It's configurable if you use the Maven Surefire or the Gradle TestNG runner, but by default I think TestNG looks in  `src/test/java` for your class names.  Additionally, I think if your running TestNG from code, as a standalone run, you might be able to adjust the path-base where it looks for classes.